# Behavior of Upper Riemann Sums of a function on an interval with respect to subpartition and partitions

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose f and the interval [a,b] are fixed, and P' is a subpartition of P. The  Upper Riemann Sum of f on the interval with respect to P' is less than the Upper Riemann Sum of f on the interval with respect to P.

Can someone explain why this is true?

Comment: The upper sun tends to over estimate the area, hence if you take a smaller partition you over estimate a bit less.

Comment: Well just consider the case when $P'$ has just one extra point compared to $P$ and consider the difference of upper sums over $P$ and $P'$. Most of the terms cancel and analyze the remaining ones. The key here is that supremum of $f$ over an interval is not exceeded by its supremum over a sub-interval.